# Group rows of a dataframe based on column mean and geo-locations

Tags: pandas

```
route_number    source_id   latitude_value  longitude_value no_of_stores
r1               676          28.15085         32.66055         23
r2               715          28.2160253       32.5214831       23
r3               345          28.2123115       32.537211        22
r4               150          28.23009         32.50323         23
r5               534          28.0949248       32.8075467       21
r6              1789          28.2204214       32.5035782       22
r7               647          28.21548         32.50238         23
r8               667          28.21132         32.51481         22
r9              2242          28.2389          32.5             19
r10              797          28.161657        32.8416816       20
r11             1097          28.1792849       32.8255522       19
r12              591          28.2513623       32.7638247       22
r13             1091          28.251208        32.7808329       21
r14             1267          28.2102213       32.8129836       21
r15             1016          28.1654648       32.8350845       19
r16              785          28.0786012       32.9513468        4
r17             1072          28.1701673       32.8382309        1
```

Mentioned above is a dataframe i am dealing with.
As you can see, the no. of stores in a route_number are different.

mean(no_of_stores) = 20 in this case

What i am looking for is,

depending on the **geo-locations**(latitude & longitude value) of my **source_id** , i want to combine multiple routes  which lie closer to each other into 1 such that the **no_of_stores** in new group are equally divided.

The condition of routes lying closer to each other can be excluded, and just merge routes with lesser no. of stores into 1 can also be done.

i.e the routes which lie closer to each other( and no_of_stores are less than the mean(no_of_stores)), combine them into 1 big route, such that **no_of_stores** in the new routes formed is the **mean** of no_of_stores column, which in case is around 19.

Final output expected something like this: (not actual)

```
route_number    new_route_no
  r1                A1     #since its already has stores greater than mean
  r2                A2
  r3                A3
  r4                A4
  ....................
  r9                A9    #(19 stores)
  r17               A9    #(1 stores)  total 20
 ....................
  r11               A11  
  r16               A11  
  r15               A15  #19 stores , since it cannot be combined further,keep as it is
```

I have tried using pandas groupby and aggregate methods, but couldnt find a way to transform this dataframe,

Any leads would be helpful.

Comment: I dont understand `i want to combine multiple routes which lie closer to each other`. How is possible get this information? Or need find it? Can you explain more?

Comment: @jezrael There's one way of doing it using euclidean distance, for every route we have a geo-location. But that would be even complex,  Can you exclude the condition of routes lying closer to each other, and just merge multiple routes where no. of stores are lesser?

Comment: @jezrael this is just test data, it can happen where, ceil(mean(no_of_stores) = 20, but maybe 2 routes have 12 stores each, and by merging them, the new stores are 24, greater than mean. Which is ok, either we can use mean(stores) or max(stores)

Comment: Not sure if understand, what is desired output? Thank you.

Comment: @jezrael you can see, r9,r11,r15,r16,r17 have lesser stores than mean(no_of_stores) = 20.
I want to merge in such manner that r9(19 stores) should be merged with route with least no_of_stores i.e r17(1 store). similarly r11(19 stores should be merged with r16(4 stores), and remaining r15(19 stores) should be kept as it as it cannot be merged with any ohter route

Comment: @jezrael i have added a sample output in que

Comment: Now understand, thank you.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/159971/discussion-between-s-ringne-and-jezrael).